# How can I access Square Feedback via their API?

Tags: square-connect, square

How can I access Square Feedback (https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/5241) via the API?

Even getting the value of the "Collect feedback from your digital receipts" toggle in the dashboard via the API would be valuable to me. (https://squareup.com/dashboard/customers/settings/feedback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is currently not possible with Square's APIs.

Comment: That's a bummer.  How do I make a feature request to Square to add this?

Comment: You could join our Slack community and post it in #feedback for our PMs to see: https://squ.re/2Hks3YE